# Wordcloud of bigram using Python

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am generating a word cloud directly from the text file using Wordcloud packge in python. 
Here is the code that I am re-using from stckoverflow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS


def random_color_func(word=None, font_size=None, position=None, orientation=None, font_path=None, random_state=None):
    h = int(360.0 * 45.0 / 255.0)
    s = int(100.0 * 255.0 / 255.0)
    l = int(100.0 * float(random_state.randint(60, 120)) / 255.0)

    return "hsl({}, {}%, {}%)".format(h, s, l)

file_content=open ("xyz.txt").read()

wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path = r'C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf',
                            stopwords = STOPWORDS,
                            background_color = 'white',
                            width = 1200,
                            height = 1000,
                            color_func = random_color_func
                            ).generate(file_content)

plt.imshow(wordcloud,interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

It is giving me wordcloud of single words. Is there any parameter in WordCloud() function to pass n-gram without formating the text file.

I want word cloud of bigram. Or words attached with underscore in display. Like:
machine_learning ( Machine and Learning would be 2 different words)

Comment: Well... instead of `file_content`, use something different, which you obtain by processing `file_content`.

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/wordcloud/wordcloud.py) is what you are using, `WordCloud` accepts a regular expression which affects how the input text is tokenized.

Comment: How to pass regular expression for bigram?

Answer (score 11):

Bigram wordclouds can easily be generated by reducing the value of collocation_threshold parameter in WordCloud.

Edit the wordcloud:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path = r'C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf',
                            stopwords = STOPWORDS,
                            background_color = 'white',
                            width = 1200,
                            height = 1000,
                            color_func = random_color_func,
                            collocation_threshold = 3               --added this to your question code, try changing this value between 1-50
                            ).generate(file_content)
```

For more info:

> *collocation_threshold: int, default=30 Bigrams must have a Dunning likelihood collocation score greater than this parameter to be counted
> as bigrams. Default of 30 is arbitrary.*

You can also find the source code for wordcloud.WordCloud here: https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/_modules/wordcloud/wordcloud.html

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Diego for your answer. This is just a continuation of Diego's answer with python code.

```
import nltk
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

WNL = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
text = 'your input text goes here'
# Lowercase and tokenize
text = text.lower()
# Remove single quote early since it causes problems with the tokenizer.
text = text.replace("'", "")
# Remove numbers from text
remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)
text = text.translate(remove_digits)
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
text1 = nltk.Text(tokens)

# Remove extra chars and remove stop words.
text_content = [''.join(re.split("[ .,;:!?‘’``''@#$%^_&*()<>{}~\n\t\\\-]", word)) for word in text1]

#set the stopwords list
stopwords_wc = set(STOPWORDS)
customised_words = ['xxx', 'yyy'] # If you want to remove any particular word form text which does not contribute much in meaning

new_stopwords = stopwords_wc.union(customized_words)
text_content = [word for word in text_content if word not in new_stopwords]

# After the punctuation above is removed it still leaves empty entries in the list.
text_content = [s for s in text_content if len(s) != 0]

# Best to get the lemmas of each word to reduce the number of similar words
text_content = [WNL.lemmatize(t) for t in text_content]

nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)  
bigrams_list = list(nltk.bigrams(text_content))
print(bigrams_list)
dictionary2 = [' '.join(tup) for tup in bigrams_list]
print (dictionary2)

#Using count vectoriser to view the frequency of bigrams
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2))
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit_transform(dictionary2)
vectorizer.vocabulary_
sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()]
words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print (words_freq[:100])

#Generating wordcloud and saving as jpg image
words_dict = dict(words_freq)
WC_height = 1000
WC_width = 1500
WC_max_words = 200
wordCloud = WordCloud(max_words=WC_max_words, height=WC_height, width=WC_width,stopwords=new_stopwords)
wordCloud.generate_from_frequencies(words_dict)
plt.title('Most frequently occurring bigrams connected by same colour and font size')
plt.imshow(wordCloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
wordCloud.to_file('wordcloud_bigram.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. Some corrections needed - customized words is spelled once with a 'z' and once with an 's'. You also have to add this 'from string import digits`

Answer (score 3):

you should use a vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2)) to get the frequencies and then use the .generate_from_frequencies method from wordcloud